# es6 setprops is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

```
class MyComponent {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <View />
    }
}

class Test() {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick() {
        this.my.setPorps({
            show: true,
        });
    }

    render(){
        return <MyComponent ref={ ref => this.my = ref }/>
    }
}
```

If I trigger onClick function, it will cause:

> undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this3.progressbar.setProps({
>                                                                   disabled:true})')

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From React docs:

> This method is deprecated and will be removed soon. This method is not available on ES6 class components that extend React.Component. Instead of calling setProps, try invoking ReactDOM.render() again with the new props.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setprops

(Also in your example you spelled it `setPorps` but it wouldn't work anyway)

It looks like your just trying to tell a component to show itself, in that case the parent state can be updated and passed as a prop to the child:

```
class Test() {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false
        };
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick() {
        this.setState({
            show: true
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <MyComponent show={this.state.show} />
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, How can I rerender part of component instead of rerender all dom.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Only want to re-render part of dom not all of dom. Beacuse, It will cause much time.

Comment: If you change the parent state and a child prop changes, React will only render what has changed in the child (if the prop affects the html output), there is no difference between that and setProps

Comment: But it will compare all dom.

Comment: @WhiteWater You need to read this, it's specifically about the situation you asked about: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html
`setProps` meant that there needed to be state held for each component instance, and was deprecated because of that. It's always going to be application-specific, you need to write an API wrapper if you really need the functionality

Comment: @DanCouper Can I use it in React Native.